# Search bar delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates, uisearchbardelegate

Here is my code :

```
- (void)searchTextDidChange:(TaggingSearchBar *)searchBar
                       text:(NSString *)searchText {


    NSArray *allPlayers = self.sessionModel.taggingModel.PlayersFromDatabase;
    [self.filterdPlayers removeAllObjects];
    if (searchText.length > 0) {
        self.isFilterd = YES;
        for (Player *p in allPlayers) {
            NSString *playerDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", p.jerseyNumber.intValue, p.fullName];
            if ([playerDescription rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound) {
                [self.filterdPlayers addObject:playerDescription];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        self.filterdPlayers = [allPlayers mutableCopy];
        self.isFilterd = NO ;
    }
}
```

Something is wrong because when I'm debugging and I put C (I have a person with the name Cat ) i get nil in self.filtredPlayers. Debugger showed hat stood in this place , and if all ok but nothing happened. What could cause this ?
I tried containsstring + addObject:p

Comment: Are you sure that at some point `playerDescription` did contain the string `Cat` in it?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. My string is C or CA and playerDescription contains 0 Tommy Cat. (0 is a jersey number)

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine in terms of functionality. To be on the safe side, I would change the inner `if` clause to this:

```
if (searchText && [playerDescription rangeOfString:searchText].length) {
```

This is safer, because if `searchText` is nil, your code would crash. I understand that you verify it before, but it's the best practice.

Moreover, I think your problem is due to the fact that you add the string object, instead of the `Player` object. When the search term is empty/nil, you add the `Player` objects:

```
self.filterdPlayers = [allPlayers mutableCopy];
```

But when the search term exists, you add the string `playerDescription` instead of the `Player` object:

```
[self.filterdPlayers addObject:p];
```

Comment: I tried add Player object aswell but it didn't work too.

Comment: When you debugged your code, did it ever reached this line:  `[self.filterdPlayers addObject:playerDescription];`?

Comment: Yes and nothing happen

Comment: Perhaps someone touches `self.filterdPlayers` afterwards? Put a breakpoint on the instance variable and see if it changes after this function has finished.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that your function is called every time the user types something in the search bar, so if they type C and then CA it will be invoked twice.

Answer (score 0):

**Use This**

```
NSString *search_str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",searchBar.text, searchText];

   if ( playerDescription.containsString(searchBar.text)) //instead of  if ([playerDescription rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound)
```

Comment: Careful using `containsString`, if this apps runs on iOS 7 it will crash (this function was introduced on iOS 8).

Comment: Use this NSRange nameRange = [playerDescription rangeOfString: search_str options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
          
            if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound )

Comment: Ok i got it. Xcode didnt use my array alloc init in setup fucn.